# How to load Facebook image url in volley

Tags: android, facebook, android-volley

Im trying to load Facbeook url image from graph api in volley image loader.
At first there was an error response returning for me 302 and 301 for redirecting the url i check the mirror library for volley and compiled it in the gradle file but now the error response is 400 i don't know what is causing that here is my code :

```
enter code here
 try {
      URL picture = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/" + fb_ID + "/picture?type=large);
      fb_Picture = picture.toString();
     } catch (MalformedURLException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
       //Loading the image
        ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/" + fb_ID + "/picture?type=large", new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("ResponseImage", "Image Load Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
                if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                    // load image into imageview
                    userImage.setOval(true);
                    userImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    userImage.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                }
            }
        });
```

how can i get the actual url image without this url or how can i load this url in volley any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: What version of FB SDK are you using? What is the source of these URL's?

Comment: latest fb sdk this is the url i parse the pic from Facebook using graph api @Skynet

Comment: I am not sure a lot has been deprecated in FB SDK, do check the change log :)

Comment: its not deprecated i did check its the way i get the profile pic from Facebook by requesting the graph api and it returns a url of the pic @Skynet

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in an app, you will need to use an access token to GET `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/<FBID>/picture?type=large`. This will return a JSON object similar to this one:

```
{
  "data": {
    "is_silhouette": false,
    "url": "https://fb.com/..."
  }
}
```

After parsing, this JSON object's `data.url` member can be used to create image view objects in your app. You can read the full documentation on this Graph API edge [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/). You can read more about [Using Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) in general [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api).

Answer (score 0):

If you are just loading a single profile image uri provided from facebook sdk, you can simply use **Asynctask** and call **BitmapFactory.decodeStream** to download the image into an Imageview. The problem with volley is it doesn't handles https images automatically due to shared security reasons and you have to manually create a custom volley Requestque with HurlStack and SSL in order to display the images.